# Error in command: dotnet database update in linux

Tags: .net, sql-server, linux, entity-framework-core

After migrations, I try to run the command:

```
dotnet-ef database update
```

The following error occurs:

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid

OS: Linux Mint 20.3

In appsettings.Development.json:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=Agenda; Integrated Security=True"
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: SQL Server for Linux doesn't include the SQL Browser service for instance name resolution, so `Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;` (against localhost) is unlikely to work on a Linux-based system. i.e.: You'll need to check which port Express is listening on and use something like `Server=localhost,yourPortNumberHere;`.

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared but the table was not created.

I changed the connection string to:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost,1433; Initial Catalog=Agenda; Integrated Security=True"
 }
```

Thanks.